# Spring JPA one to many relationship error

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I got Spring BOOT Application and, I am using Spring JPA
I have two Entitiys

```
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(
                strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
        )
        @Column(
                name = "id",
                unique = true,
                updatable = false
        )
        private Long id;
    
    
        @Column(
                name = "firstname",
                nullable = false,
                columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    
        )
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(
                name = "lastName",
                nullable = false,
                columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    
        )
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column(
                name = "password",
                nullable = false,
                columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    
        )
        private String password;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

  public Author(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String password, List<Course> courses) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.password = password;
    this.courses = courses;
}

//getters setters existing
}
```

and

```
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            unique = true,
            nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "name",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String name;

    @Column(
            name = "description",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String description;

    @Column(
            name = "price",
            nullable = false
    )
    private BigDecimal price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "author_id",
            nullable = false
    )
    private Author author;
//getters and setters exist
}
```

and also repo interface for Author

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author,Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new Author (a.id,a.firstName,a.lastName,a.password,a.courses) FROM Author a WHERE a.id =:id")
    Optional<Author> findById(Long id);
}
```

now i have some data in db where Author have some courses
but when i am trying to fetch it in some controller by mentioned repo it throws
this exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.educraft.am.model.Author]. Expected arguments are: long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Collection
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
at
```

now all I what is to be able to retrieve author data from db which includes a List of courses.